# How do you use list comprehensions in Python for sum of squares in a list?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, list-comprehension

This is the data provided.

```
# Data on probability of expansion success by country estimates
success_estimates = {
    'Australia': [0.6, 0.33, 0.11, 0.14],
    'France': [0.66, 0.78, 0.98, 0.2],
    'Italy': [0.6],
    'Brazil': [0.22, 0.22, 0.43],
    'USA': [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
    'England': [0.45],
    'Canada': [0.25, 0.3],
    'Argentina': [0.22],
    'Greece': [0.45, 0.66, 0.75, 0.99, 0.15, 0.66],
    'Morocco': [0.29],
    'Tunisia': [0.68, 0.56],
    'Egypt': [0.99],
    'Jamaica': [0.61, 0.65, 0.71],
    'Switzerland': [0.73, 0.86, 0.84, 0.51, 0.99],
    'Germany': [0.45, 0.49, 0.36]
}
```

This is the practice question and a copy of my closest, but non-successful code.

Using list comprehensions, write a script to create a list of lists called sum_squares_list, where each element of the list is a two-item list [country name, value]. The value item in the list should be the sum of squares of that country's success estimates. For example, one element of sum_squares_list should be for Jamaica, where the two-item list is [Jamaica, 1.2987] (since 1.2987 = 0.61^2 + 0.65^2 + 0.71^2).

My Closest but Incorrect Code

```
sum_squares_list = [[i, sum(success_estimates[i])] for i in success_estimates]
sum_squares_list

[['Australia', 1.1800000000000002],
 ['France', 2.62],
 ['Italy', 0.6],
 ['Brazil', 0.87],
 ['USA', 1.0],
 ['England', 0.45],
 ['Canada', 0.55],
 ['Argentina', 0.22],
 ['Greece', 3.66],
 ['Morocco', 0.29],
 ['Tunisia', 1.2400000000000002],
 ['Egypt', 0.99],
 ['Jamaica', 1.97],
 ['Switzerland', 3.9299999999999997],
 ['Germany', 1.2999999999999998]]
```

I am having lots of trouble trying to find the sum of squares. Summing all those values is easy enough, but how do I square the elements before I sum it?

Comment: Please post the data and code directly into your question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to calculate the sum of the squared estimates for each country.

```
sum_squares_list = [[country, sum(estimate ** 2 for estimate in estimates)] 
                    for country, estimates in success_estimates.items()]
>>> sum_squares_list
[['Australia', 0.5005999999999999],
 ['France', 2.0444],
 ['Italy', 0.36],
 ['Brazil', 0.28169999999999995],
 ['USA', 0.38],
 ['England', 0.2025],
 ['Canada', 0.1525],
 ['Argentina', 0.0484],
 ['Greece', 2.6388],
 ['Morocco', 0.0841],
 ['Tunisia', 0.7760000000000001],
 ['Egypt', 0.9801],
 ['Jamaica', 1.2987],
 ['Switzerland', 3.2183],
 ['Germany', 0.5722]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dictionary `.items()` iterable and then sum the squares of the items within the dictionary keys; e.g.,

```
[(k, sum([x * x for x in v])) for k, v in success_estimates.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down a bit. How do we use a list comprehension to get a list of squares of a list of numbers?

```
list = [0.45, 0.66, 0.75, 0.99, 0.15, 0.66]

squares = [x * x for x in list]
```

How do we then sum that?

```
list = [0.45, 0.66, 0.75, 0.99, 0.15, 0.66]

sum_of_squares = sum([x * x for x in list])
```

We can leave out the braces.

```
list = [0.45, 0.66, 0.75, 0.99, 0.15, 0.66]

sum_of_squares = sum(x * x for x in list)
```

Now, you need to just apply that to this problem. You will likely find it helpful to work on the list of keys for the `success_estimates` dictionary.